# Issue with ZBar library in Android Nogut

Tags: android, android-support-library, zbar, zbar-sdk

I am using Z Bar library in my Android application and everything is working
fine except it is showing some warnings on application starting.
Warning message: " detected problems with app native libraries text relocation
libiconv.so: text relocations, libzbarjni.so: text relocations" .Can you please look into this issue. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbT8i.png)

build.gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.wakascaner"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```